# Interface 'mylogginginterface' not found in dblogger.php file

Tags: php, oop

Please help me to find solution is that did code already. but when i run the program it's say Interface 'mylogginginterface' not found in dblogger.php file. i am confused where i am wrong. please check my code.

Check these files please.

Index.php file

```
             <?php


               include_once("classes/dblogger.php");
               include_once("classes/loggerinterface.php");

               $logging = new dbloggingsystem();

                $profile = new userprofile($logging);

              echo $profile->createuser();

                ?>
```

loggerinterface.php file

```
              <?php

               interface mylogginginterface {

                public function log($message);
               }

               ?>
```

dblogger.php file

```
                   <?php

                  /**  **/


                 class dbloggingsystem implements mylogginginterface
                  {

                 public function log($message) {

                     echo "Logging message of user is:- $message";
                  }

                  }
```

userprofile.php

```
             <?php

             class userprofile
               {
                 private $fullloggingsystem;

              public function createuser() {

             $this->fullloggingsystem->log("user created");
             }

            public function updateuser() {


    $this->fullloggingsystem->log("user update");
}

public function deleteuser() {



    $this->fullloggingsystem->log("user deleted");
}

public function __construct(mylogginginterface $myloggingsystem){

      $this->fullloggingsystem = $myloggingsystem;

}
   }
```

Please check it where i am wrong and why this error occur. thanks in advance.

Comment: its simple just include loggerinterface.php file first then dblogger.php file

Comment: i already include loggerinterface.php file in index.php file

Comment: you have to include loggerinterface file first then dbloggr file watch my answer below

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to complete the [tour] and read [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to include your loggerinterface file first then dblogger.php

```
inlcude_once ("loggerinterface.php");
inlcude_once ("dblogger.php");
```

Comment: because you have to declare interface first then you can implies it into your class